# PHP problem with JOIN statement in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, foreach

I have two tables: 'events_archive' and 'demo_users'.  In the events table, each event has a unique `ref_id` value, a `demo_id` value (the user ID of the demonstrator who participated in the event) and a `client_id` value (the user ID of the client who participated in the event).  In the demos table, each demonstrator has a unique `id` value that corresponds to the `demo_id` in the events table.

What I want to do is list all demonstrators (from the demos table) that participated in events that a particular client did.  I'm getting the particular client's user ID with session data.

So say the `client_id` value is 4, I want to list all the individual demonstrators that have shared an event (i.e. shared a row in the table).  I'm currently using this in my CodeIgniter model:

```
function demos($mid){    
   $this->db->select('demo_users.*');
   $this->db->from('demo_users');
   $this->db->join('events_archive','events_archive.demo_id = demo_users.id');
   $this->db->where('events_archive.client_id',$mid);
   $this->db->limit(10);
   $this->db->order_by('users_demonstrators.products_sold','asc');
   $demos = $this->db->get(); 
   foreach($demos->result() as $demo){
      echo $demo->first_name;
   }
}
```

But instead of listing the demonstrators individually, it duplicates them over and over.  Instead of listing Demonstrator A, Demonstrator D, Demonstrator F, etc. it lists Demonstrator A, Demonstrator A, Demonstrator A, etc. Does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$this->db->select('demo_users.*')` try `$this->db->select('*')` and instead of `echo $demo->first_name;` try `var_dump($demo);`.

My guess is that `Demonstrator A` has many records in `events_archive`. You join the two tables and as a result, each matching record in `events_archive` gets added with the columns from `demo_users`. That's why you get multiple `demo_users.*` - but the records have different `events_archive.*` values.

You maybe want to try [SELECT DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: I added `$this->db->distinct();` and it worked perfectly. Thanks